# What is the formula for magnetic field strength outside a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, maxwell-equations

I know that for an ideal solenoid the magnetic field outside the solenoid is zero, however, I wanted to know what the magnetic field outside a finite solenoid would be. I did find a [research paper by NASA](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/%7Eee08173/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/finite-solenoid.pdf) on this topic and the author does establish a formula for this, however, I was not able to grasp it because it uses 'elliptic integrals of first and second kind' and I have no clue as to what they are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the magnetic flux density "outside" the solenoid when AC current is passing through it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184021/)

Comment: Duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184021/

Comment: I'm afraid that the answer involving the "elliptic integrals of the first and second kind" is the best answer you're going to get.  Have you read through the [Wikipedia page on them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)?  If there's stuff that confuses you there, it might be worth asking about it over on [Math.SE].

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yea I realized that is the only way to go, so I did check out the wikipedia page and took help from a mathematically-inclined friend of mine... I still do not understand these integrals but I did figure out how to apply them by using series approximation. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For a perfect solenoid there is no field outside. In a perfect solenoid the current would be circular about the axis, so that there is no component parallel to the axis. In a real solenoid there is a current component parallel to the axis which causes a field outside the solenoid. This field should be small compared to the field inside the solenoid.