# Is the magnetic field outside a solenoid almost null for AC current?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, magnetostatics

Despite an answer to [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184021/what-is-the-magnetic-flux-density-outside-the-solenoid-when-ac-current-is-pass), I'm not so sure the magnetic flux outside an infinite ideal solenoid is null whenever the current is AC. I've seen no real proof of that, and the Biot-Savart law which is often used to prove the DC case ceases to be valid at AC. So, do you know a proof that is valid for AC?

In the practical case where we can do nothing but a finite long spiral solenoid, notice that the component of the current along the axis of the solenoid can be cancelled by adding a second layer of wiring in the opposite direction. So, I believe, we can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Bio-Savart does not apply to AC currents. It is a law of magnetostatics. For AC currents we have to use the full Maxwell equations or a retarded potential formula like Jefimenko's equations. In practice a thin cylindrical structure like a solenoid develops a traveling wave solution with a substantial outside field that is often used in antenna designs and for applications like resonant tuning.